# Embed PDF for Android and iOS

Tags: pdf, android, ios

Anyone know a way to embed PDFs so that both iOS (iPads and iPhones) and Androids (all versions after 2.2) can view?

My current site c.theborneopost.com does not support tablets... only desktop with Adobe Reader.

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak for Android but a [quick search](http://www.google.co.uk/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=android%20pdf%20handling#q=android%20pdf%20handling&hl=en&tbs=clue:1,qdr%3ay&prmd=imvns&source=lnt&sa=X&ei=yn87T_qsJ8qR0AXhpcxs&ved=0CBEQpwUoBQ&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=38ae36cda5a22469&biw=1600&bih=799) would [seem to suggest](http://www.downloadatoz.com/file-extensions/tutorial,10705,how-to-view-pdf-file-on-android-cell-phone.html) it's handled by an app or free reader app rather than the browser.

The iPhone opens PDF's on the fly in Safari and if you save them it saves them in iBook.

You don't have to do anything special to achieve this just link to the PDF as you normally would.